# Is there an error in Edwards's proof of the continuity of the function to which a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions converges?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, calculus-of-variations

This question regards [Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, by C.H. Edwards](https://books.google.com/books/about/Advanced_Calculus_of_Several_Variables.html?id=sZIFcJ8DJAIC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Am I correct that there is an error in Edwards's proof of the following theorem?

> Theorem V1-1.2 Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$.
>   Let $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuous
>   real-valued functions on $\mathcal{S}$. If $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$
>   converges uniformly to the funtion $f:\mathcal{S}\to\mathbb{R},$then
>   $f$ is continuous.
>
> PROOF: Given $\varepsilon>0$, first choose $N$ sufficiently large
>   that $\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$
>   for all $x\in\mathcal{S}$ (by the uniform convergence). Then, given
>   $x_{0}\in\mathcal{S}$, choose $\delta>0$ such that
>
> $$
> x\in\mathcal{S},\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta\implies\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}
> $$
>
> (by the continuity of $f_{N}$ at $x_{0}$). If $x\in\mathcal{S}$
>   and $\left|x-x_{0}\right|<\delta$, then it follows that
>
> $$
> \left|f\left[x\right]-f\left[x_{0}\right]\right|\le\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon,
> $$
>
> so $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.

The attached diagram shows that, if both $\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|>\frac{\varepsilon}{6}$
(magenta) and $\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|>\frac{\varepsilon}{6}$
(blue) , then $\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|>\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ (red).

So, it seems to me, Edwards's inequality does not follow from what
has been given.

I propose that asserting $\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$
and $\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$
does imply $\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2};$
so that

$$
\left|f\left[x\right]-f\left[x_{0}\right]\right|\le\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon,
$$

will repair the proof.
[image]

---

Edit to add a second diagram so the casual reader will not be misled by the first one.  Note the color-coding is different than that of the first diagram.
[image]

Comment: Last line in the proof shoulde be $\left|f\left[x\right]-f\left[x_{0}\right]\right|\le\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[\color{red}{x_0}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Edwards made a typo. The last line in the proof should be
$$\left|f\left[x\right]-f\left[x_{0}\right]\right|\le\left|f\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x\right]-f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]\right|+\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[\color{\red}{x_0}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon,$$
because $\left|f_{N}\left[x_{0}\right]-f\left[x_0\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ due to uniform convergence (it holds for all $x\in\mathcal{S}$, so in particular for $x_0$.)

Comment: Meh!  You have no idea how much time and effort I expended trying to shove 10 Lbs of excrement into a 5 Lbs bag!

Comment: Well, that is the downside of math. I like the picture you made by the way.